# Typewriter effect on text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to add typewriter animation to my html text as soon as the url loads, using the code below. Please check why this might not be working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p onload="typeWriter()" id="demo"></p>
  <style>
    p {
      color: Black;
      font-family: arial;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var i = 0;
    var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
    var speed = 50;

    function typeWriter() {
      if (i < txt.length) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cut `onload="typeWriter()"` from p and add it to the `body`, `p` don't have any on-load event like this, replace body start tag with `<body onload="typeWriter()">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onload=""` attribute does not work on a `<p>` element (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)). I'd suggest doing that in JavaScript instead:

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", typeWriter);
```

```css
p   {
  color: Black;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

---

Alternatively you can specify `onload` on the `<body>` tag:

```html
<body onload="typeWriter()">
```

Answer (score -1):

**The onload="" attribute does not work on p  tag **

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load", typeWriter);
```

```css
p{
  color: Black;
  font-family: arial;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p  id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```